# Convert HTTP ASP.NET REST Service to HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, wcf

I have a working rest web service setup on a server which I can hit with SoapUI.
I have setup an SSL Certificate and setup a new binding in IIS to point 443 to my service and tested that the https routing works by hosting just an html file.
But when I try and host my existing rest web service on HTTPS it doesn't respond in SOAP UI. Response is:

HTTP/1.1 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2016 16:41:19 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Am I doing something wrong in SoapUI, or do I need to change some config?

The web.config setup is as follows:

```
<service name="WebServices.FacilityService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Web.Interfaces.IFacility" behaviorConfiguration="web">
</endpoint>
```

I did try this instead, but no different.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"  contract="Web.Interfaces.IFacility" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior">
</endpoint>
```

With this in the bindings section:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
        <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: What binding was configured on your IIS application pool? Did you configure the site to use basic authentication? What does the behavior element in Web.config look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do you also get this error when you browse the svc? If so, maybe you can get the details about your error by adding this bit inside your behavior section:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

Also, please make sure that the enabled authentication type matches you client credential type in your binding element. It looks like only anonymous authentication is enabled right now. If not, please make sure to modify your binding element accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  A bit of extra error info helped me work out it was down to the fact that my behaviour configuration name didn't match what I had got elsewhere in the file, ie. behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" should have been behaviorConfiguration="web"